# What is the difference between maven dependencies org.apache.commons:commons-io and commons-io:commons-io?

Tags: maven, dependencies, apache-commons

Maven repositories contain these two dependencies: [org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-io/1.3.2/) and [commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/). What is the difference and which one I should be using in my pom.xml?

In general some of the apache commons packages are located in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/ and most of the `commons-*` packages are located here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.

Comment: I'm just fighting this confusion too. To make matter worse, on Maven repo you'll learn that for commons-io the groupId was changed from org.apache.commons to commons-io, but for commons-lang it's the other way around.

Comment: Beware that if you had an old version of org.apache.commons:commons-io (for instance, in your local maven .m2/repository) it won't have a "relocation" tag in there, so if you have both it and io-commons as dependency/transitive dependencies you may end up with two different versions of the jars in your classpath (yikes maven).  To fix remove folder ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-io to force redownload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) website. the latest release is 2.0.1. 1.3.2 is pretty old. Given this information, the repository in http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/ holds the latest releases and is the right one to use.

[This](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@commons.apache.org/msg05525.html) related mail thread makes interesting reading.

Answer (score 13):

The deployment of

> org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2

Was a [mistake](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-244) that was ultimately fixed by relocating:

[POM of `org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.pom)

To use `commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2`.

The mistake was likely an attempt to migrate the Commons IO library to use the [current naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32184114/2646526) for Maven groupIds.

Answer (score 1):

The two dependencies look the same. I would prefer to use commons-io:commons-io, cause the pom of org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2 is wrong (wrong groupId!)

The artifacts located at this position: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/ are newer in date than the others.