# In maven it's "org.apache.commons.collections:commons-collections" the same as "commons-collections:commons-collections"?

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

I just saw on my pom files that there are two different group id's  for Apache commons-collections:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons.collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Are these two the same? and if they are the same, which one should is use by convention?

Comment: The second one doesn't exist in public Maven repo: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.apache.commons.collections%22 So impossible to say.

Comment: The groupId is not `org.apache.commons.collections` but `commons-collections` in your link. I don't understand.

Comment: I didn't test it but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work since the artifact doesn't exist in public Maven repo.

Comment: @j2gl The correct groupId depends upon which version of the artifact you want to use. Modern releases use the `org.apache...` variant.

Comment: Thanks @Tanuki for your help, there was a custom artifact installed on our custom maven repo (nexus) with a custom hibernate and commons-collections on legacy.

Comment: Yes @Duncan, as you said they change it on to org.apache... on commons-collections version 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For commons-collections version 3, there is no groupId: org.apache.commons.collections, so prior to version 4 use:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Since version 4:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that the **artifact id has changed to *commons-collections4***.

Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COLLECTIONS-382

Comment: They changed the groupId of Commons Collections to `org.apache.commons` so the project would finally adhere to the [best practice of basing the groupId on the domain name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184114/apache-commons-inconsistent-naming-convention).