# android studio duplicate zip entry transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguard

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem, gradle downloads two times library: commons-io-1.3.2.jar and I have in external libraries: commons-io-1.3.2 and 1_commons-io-1.3.2

I see in logs:

.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/b6dde38349ba9bb5e6ea6320531eae969985dae5/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
    gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2/b6dde38349ba9bb5e6ea6320531eae969985dae5/commons-io-1.3.2.jar

end error:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/**/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/Users/**/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2/b6dde38349ba9bb5e6ea6320531eae969985dae5/commons-io-1.3.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-io-1.3.2.jar:org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class]))
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':VFWallet:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForApp'.

> Job failed, see logs for details

Comment: if you have gradle download your dependency files there is no need for external libraries. you can remove the external libraries

Comment: but also in gradle caches I see one from commons-io and one org.apache.commons which is incorrect

Comment: I have the exact same problem—with commons-io as well—and cannot see how it might be fixed. Deleting the cache, having gradle rebuild it, doesn't help. Neither does invalidating caches in Android Studio. I don't include any external dependencies via .jar files; gradle “compile” only.

Comment: Hi I fixed it, update the apache library, I removed: 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2' update it if you need it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating the **apache library**:

```
'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566734/what-is-the-difference-between-maven-dependencies-org-apache-commonscommons-io) helped me