# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' although i have few methods

Tags: android, android-multidex

I imported a code from github and tried to run it on my device, and encountered this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

When I googled it, I found out that it has something to do with the **number of methods** where the code is getting too big, but it's not the fact that it only contains one Java class with a couple of methods. What else could be the problem?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `rebuild project` and `clear cache and restart`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html Please go through this link, It doesn't need all methods to be in your project. You may have many dependencies in your project. Remove unwanted dependencies.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015038/cause-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-apache-commo

Answer (score 0):

Many times it's not your method references that exceeds the 64k limit.It's the method references in the libraries you use such ad Http legacy library , it has a huge number of methods .. I've found that if I include Http legacy to any project than i've to enable multidex.
read this for more info
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

Add "multiDexEnabled true" in your build.gradle file under the defaultConfig.